# Parametrisation in HP LoadRunner

Tags: automated-tests, loadrunner

I have parameters table like this:

customerCode, productType

153770, deposit

153754, credit

152002, deposit

458712, deposit

785215, loan

In one of scripts I need to select random customerCode, for which productType is deposit. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

What is your thought on how you would approach this?  Note: this solution will leverage your foundation skills in 'C,' the default language of most LoadRunner virtual user types,  to introduce a loop with an exit condition as well as programmatic control of advancing parameters.

- If you are using a Java Virtual User, A JavaScript Virtual User, a VB Virtual user or a C# virtual user for .Net virtual user types then your code would be in the appropriate language for those types and not 'C.'   The logic of the code however will be identical.

Answer (score 0):

paramterize the customer code and product type.
go to parameter properties of customer code and choose random

and for product type choose same line as customer code